# 3D Plot of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas Dataframe that has 4 columns - 3 columns of data and the 4th indicating cluster number

```
        Col1       Col2       Col3  class
0      41.780730  -1.306569 -28.856727      0
1      36.421576  -7.654914 -32.675033      0
2      32.721677 -13.621913 -35.019806      0
3      42.028039 -12.280224 -39.521991      0
4      40.498716  -9.311412 -33.008553      0
...          ...        ...        ...    ...
14975 -54.303420  -5.444276  31.720262      1
14976 -63.230109 -12.673256  49.581873      1
14977 -63.609974 -11.004379  49.994068      1
14978 -52.682472 -10.969886  32.483284      1
14979 -37.329985 -19.290387  11.959876      1

[14980 rows x 4 columns]
```

I want to create a 3D scatter plot with the first 3 columns as X,Y,Z axes values and *class* denoting which class it belongs to (use it for colouring)

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to use `matplotlib`'s `scatter3D()` (see documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.scatter3D)), e.g.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(df['Col1'], df['Col2'], df['Col3'], c=df['class'])
plt.show()
```

where `df` is the *data frame* variable.

Comment: I Have 14k rows. But I don't see that many values. There's only like 5 values

Comment: @PrateekNarendra any error/warning message? Have you tried with dummy data? This seems to work for me with 14k elements.